# Bootstrap modals don't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I need to close 2 modals in the same time. Why?

I have 2 modals, first shows the information and the second shows a exclude confirmation. When i close the second i want to close all modals.

*This is in ASP.NET MVC and RAZOR.*

This JS dont work, can you help me? **Thanks**!!

```js
    $(function () {

        $(".close-modal-edit").click(function () {
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
        });

    });
```

```html
        <!-- FIRST MODAL -->        
        <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <div class="modal-body text-left">
                                <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CONFIRMATION MODAL -->
        <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="dialog-exclude" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-content modal-content-edit">
                <div class="close-modal close-modal-edit" data-dismiss="modal">
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                            <div class="modal-body text-left">
                                <a class="btn btn-success pull-right close-modal-edit" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work for me. Looping through the modal objects and closing them individually.

```
   $(".close-modal-edit").click(function () {
       $.each($(".modal"), function (i, obj) {
            $(obj).modal('hide');
        });
   });
```

Note: looks like your original `$('.modal')modal('hide');` works for me as well here's a fiddle, use it this as a base, see if it works in your project, and if not we'll need more info about your project. http://jsfiddle.net/hxo5kccs/

Comment: `$(".modal").each(function () { $(this).modal('hide'); } );` does the same thing depending on your preferences

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove  data-dismiss="modal" from both modal and try?

Comment: I tried, nothing now closed. Before, if I opened just one of Modal, they closed, the problem is when I try to open two and want to close both at the same time. Understood?

Comment: then  "$(".close-modal-edit").click(" event is no firing,
you can add href="javascript:void(0);" for the anchor(<a tag) and try